# I will ask my colleague Ann to help us with sending (of)invitations/send invitations

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

Which is more idiomatic?

> 1. I will ask my colleague Ann to help us with sending invitations
> 2. I will ask my colleague Ann to help us with sending of invitations
> 3. I will ask my colleague Ann to help us (to) send invitations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentence 3 ("to help us send") is the most natural to my ear.

Sentence 1 ("to help us with sending") also sounds okay.

Sentence 2 ("to help us with sending of") does not sound natural to me. It should be "to help us with **the** sending of." But even in this form it sounds a little stilted or overly formal.

Comment: Thank you, @randomhead! It's interesting. What does the definite article do so that 'of' becomes ok?

Comment: "The sending of invitations" is seen as a distinct task, probably implying that there are a lot of them to send. As @randomhead says, it's a bit more formal.

Comment: @i_yre_b "send" in sentence 3 is a verb (infinitive) but "sending" in sentences 1/2 is a gerund, which is a noun. See [this WordReference thread](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/the-a-noun-of-noun.2547165/) discussing what article to use with the "[noun] of [noun]" construction.